# Can community users reference internal users in Chatter?

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed

In my organization the Account object has public read/write on the sharing settings, and my community users can only @mention the system administrators and other people from the same community on chatter. I would like for them to be able to @mention internal users as well. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think they can only mention members of the community. I believe you can add members by profile in the community settings. You could add all your internal users to the community this way.

If you think about it, this should be how it works. How else would your internal users be able to respond on chatter?

[How to manage community membership](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_members.htm&type=5)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I forgot to mention on the original question. But is it possible to allow other communities to see it as well?

Comment: Theoretically, every community should be associated with a specific profile so if you added the profile to both communities, users should be able to @mention across communities. The issue remains the same in that the users from the other community will have to log into the community the chatter originated from to respond.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira the documentation states: **"Can mention people specific to the current community."** . More details can be found here: [Who Can See What in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_visibility.htm&type=5)